ELSA Workflow Can't Read the HttpRequest Result of the HttpEndpoint Activity
I have been trying to run this basic ELSA workflow (3.1) to capture the HTTP request in a variable because I wanted to check if the request is of type POST or GET.
protected override void Build(IWorkflowBuilder builder)
{
var httpRequestVariable = builder.WithVariable();
  builder.Root = new Sequence
  {
      Activities =
      {
          new HttpEndpoint
          {
              Path = new("request"),
              SupportedMethods = new(new[]{HttpMethods.Post}),
              CanStartWorkflow = true,
              Result = new(httpRequestVariable)
          },
                          
          // Write a response.
          new WriteHttpResponse
          {                    
              Content = new(context =>
              {
                  var request = httpRequestVariable.Get(context);
                  
                  return new
                  {
                      Message = $"Method: {request?.Method}, Scheme : {request?.Scheme} , IsHttps: {request?.IsHttps}",
                  };
              }),
          }
      }
  };

}
When I run the workflow, I receive this error
Stack overflow.
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethod(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.QCallModule, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternal(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.ReadOnlySpan1<IntPtr>, System.ReadOnlySpan1)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandle(Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[], System.RuntimeTypeHandle[])
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(System.Reflection.MetadataToken, System.Reflection.MetadataImport ByRef, System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, System.Reflection.MetadataToken, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, ListBuilder1<System.Object> ByRef, System.RuntimeType ByRef, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo ByRef, Boolean ByRef) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder1<System.Object> ByRef, System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, ListBuilder1<System.Object>) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.RuntimeType, System.RuntimeType, Boolean) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.FSharpCoreReflectionProxy.GetFSharpCoreAssembly(System.Type) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.FSharpCoreReflectionProxy.IsFSharpType(System.Type) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.FSharpTypeConverterFactory.CanConvert(System.Type) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetBuiltInConverter(System.Type) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(System.Type, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions) at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions+CachingContext.CreateCacheEntry(System.Type, CachingContext) at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoInternal(System.Type, Boolean, System.Nullable1, Boolean, Boolean)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.GetTypeInfo(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Type)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(System.Object, System.Type, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)
at Elsa.Workflows.Serialization.Converters.PolymorphicObjectConverter.Write(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Object, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].GetMemberAndWriteJson(System.Object, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef, System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter1[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon> ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnWriteResume(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].WriteCore(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Serialize(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Object) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SerializeAsObject(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Object)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStringAsObject(System.Object, System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo)
at Elsa.Workflows.Serialization.Converters.PolymorphicObjectConverter.Write(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Object, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].GetMemberAndWriteJson(System.Object, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef, System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter1[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon> ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnWriteResume(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].WriteCore(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Serialize(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Object) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SerializeAsObject(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Object)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStringAsObject(System.Object, System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo)
at Elsa.Workflows.Serialization.Converters.PolymorphicObjectConverter.Write(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Object, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].GetMemberAndWriteJson(System.Object, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef, System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter1[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon> ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnWriteResume(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].WriteCore(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Serialize(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Object) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SerializeAsObject(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Object)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStringAsObject(System.Object, System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo)
at Elsa.Workflows.Serialization.Converters.PolymorphicObjectConverter.Write(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Object, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].GetMemberAndWriteJson(System.Object, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef, System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter1[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon> ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnWriteResume(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.__Canon, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.WriteStack ByRef)
